# How to replace Fragments of different types?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

Good morning. I'm developing an app in which I have a main layout that extends from activity and inside this one I have one fragment of one data type, in my case FragmentCover (it's a class).

During my app, I push a button and I want to change this fragment layout for another layout that extends from fragment but of different type, called SongList.

My problem is that I have defined this fragment for the class of Cover and when I change I don't have any problem, but when I want to get the views and set to one variable of my class, the funciont `songList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.songList);` it's null and it gives me error.

I put it here what I do.

**layout**

```
<fragment android:name="es.xxx.ui.FragmentCover"
    android:id="@+id/pruebaa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/songBar"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"/>
```

**mainclass change**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(isCoverFragment){
                FragmentSongList fragmentSongList = new FragmentSongList();
                transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.pruebaa, fragmentSongList);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                transaction.addToBackStack("LIST");
                transaction.commit();
                isCoverFragment=false;
            }
            else{
                transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.pruebaa, fragmentCover);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                transaction.addToBackStack("COVER");
                transaction.commit();
                getSongCover();
                isCoverFragment=true;
            }
```

The problem is not the change, is when I try to make the findViewById, it's probabbly because it doesn't load the view associated with FragmentSongList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to use a FrameLayout inside your layout file, instead of defining the Fragment in .xml**

Into that FrameLayout, you can inflate any Fragment you want.
Just **inflate the First Fragment you want to be displayed directly in your onCreate(...) method.**

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">       
        </FrameLayout>
```

This is how to **inflate the Fragments programatically** into the FrameLayout.

```
 FragmentSongList fragmentSongList = new FragmentSongList();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentSongList);
         transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
         transaction.addToBackStack("LIST");
         transaction.commit();
```

You can **leave the code inside your onClick() method just the way it is**, just **change the id to "content_frame".** Furthermore, as mentioned above you will have to **inflate the first Fragment that should be displayed inside your onCreate(...) method.**

Comment: So, if I'm not wrong I change the fragment into my main_activity.xml and change it by framelayout and then I inflate one of that classes, isn't it? In that case, it's necessary that my classes extends from fragment?

Comment: Instead of defining the Fragment in .xml like you did, you use a FrameLayout in .xml - then you inflate / replace in your onCreate method using FragmentManager yes. And yes, your Classes need to extend Fragment, otherwise they cannot be "replaced" using the FragmentManager.

Comment: I'll proove and I tell you, but I think it's the key to make it works

Comment: Yes, this is definitely correct, I use it in my projects all the time and it works just fine :-)

Comment: It works, but I have a question, when I change of layout and comeback to the previous one, my cover has dissapeared. I try to do a setter of views after do the first commit translation, but it gives me error because it said that getView() is null