# After popping the backstack, my Fragments are not being garbage collected

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

After popping the backstack, my Fragments are not being garbage collected? Their `onStop()` methods are called, but not their `onDestroyView()` or `onDestroy()` methods.

How can I ensure that their `onDestory()` methods are called?

I made the mistake of making a "God Activity", and all my fragments `.replace()` a single container `FrameLayout`. Let's say I have four fragments, `FragA`, `FragB`, `FragC`, and `FragD`, with a backstack that looks something like this:

`FragA` -> `FragB` -> `FragC` -> `FragD`

`FragD is the only visible fragment. Then, I call .`popBackstack()`

`FragA` -> `FragB` -> `FragC`  =!= `FragD`

`FragD` has been detached, and `FragC` is now visible to the user. When try to instantiate a new `FragD` (from `FragC`), it's created, and there are two instances of `FragD` on my heap. And the first `FragD` instance's `onDestroyView()` is not called.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: here's an example of how I am currecntly replacing fragments in my UI:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new SearchScreenFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

EDIT2: `onDetach()` isn't being called either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been using this: `getChildFragmentManager()`:

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500935/891242