# Strange behaviour replacing fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I've been working for several months in an app. The version uploaded to the playstore works fine. Recently, doing some improvements, the whole app has started to work in a very strange way.

If you swith between fragments, after a while it does not inflate properly the fragments, putting always the content of the first one. So, if you switch the fragment, the action bar changes but **the content is always the same** (and you cannot interact with it).

Here is a quick video of the error https://streamable.com/9exa

I am going crazy as there is no log or trace whatsoever.

I am using the usual way of swithing fragments and the most intriguing part is that at the beginning everything works ok:

```
Fragment fragment = getSelectedFragment(index); // returns the desired fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

//Pop backstack
for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
}

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
               .addToBackStack(null)
               .commit();
```

Do anyone has any kind of idea what could be happening here? Thanks!

**edit**: I also have tried to clear the backstack in case it was the problem, but it doesn't change anything

**solved**: As I explain in my answer, I have discovered that is a problem related to a SwipeRefreshLayout. More information about this problem can be found at [When switch fragment with SwipeRefreshLayout during refreshing, fragment freezes but actually still work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057449/when-switch-fragment-with-swiperefreshlayout-during-refreshing-fragment-freezes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem.

It seems that a [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) was the one causing all the problems. One of my fragments was using it, and after switching fragments a couple of times it gets stuck.

Removing it, or disabling it *setEnabled(false)* solves all the problems.

I hope it will help to anyone that is having the same problem!

Another thread in SO that refers to the same problem: [When switch fragment with SwipeRefreshLayout during refreshing, fragment freezes but actually still work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057449/when-switch-fragment-with-swiperefreshlayout-during-refreshing-fragment-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

What fragments are you using?

I had some strange behaviour using framework fragments, and i switched to V4 and everything worked fine

Comment: I just replaced all the fragments to v4, but sadly the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link: [FragmentManager popBackStack doesn't remove fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499198/fragmentmanager-popbackstack-doesnt-remove-fragment)

I am using the following code in my activity for switching between fragments and it is working fine. My app's minSdkVersion is 15.

```
    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```